# Bootstrap Modal + PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So I can attest that I am an idiot/newb/.
I am looking for a simple way to have ajax transfer an ID to a modal.
Which then takes that modal that has php and provides the necessary variables to be shown.

Ex.

Table

```
===============================

[Button] | Data | Data | Data | 

===============================
```

[Click Button(ID)] -> Modal Pops up -> Name: Data , Email: Data, Username: Data

I don't know if this kinda helps out.
I was able to figure out how to have the modal add information to a database but I can't seem to figure out how to pull data from the ID to modal and populate it.

Thanks for any help I can get!

EDIT: (UPDATE)
This is my index page that displays all phone inventory. The "View" pops up the modal but gives me random information, it is an active ID but not the one that is current to the order.

Hope this helps. ( I'll take any help or criticism )

```
    <?php
        include "../includes/db_connect.php";
        $page = "chauffeur";
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        if($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == 1){ }
        elseif($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == "")
        {
            header("location: http://wcl-wamp/"); 
        }
     ?>
     <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>WCL WebApp</title>
        <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/td/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .body{margin: 0 40px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('../nav.php'); ?>
    <div class="body">
            <div class="row">
                <h3><b>Phone Inventory</b></h3>
            <div id="modal-results" ></div>
    <?php
          try {
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM phone_inventory');
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    if(count($result)) {
                            foreach($result as $row){
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                } ?>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Phone Profile - ID <?= $row['id']; ?></b></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="test" role="form">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone_number">Phone #
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" value="<?= $row['phone_number']; ?>"></label>
                        <label for="device_id">Device ID
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="device_id" name="device_id" value="<?= $row['device_id']; ?>"></label>
                        <label for="device_manufacturer">Device Manufacturer
                        <input type="text" name="device_manufacturer" id="device_manufacturer" class="form-control" value="<?= $row['device_manufacturer']; ?>" /></label>
                        <label for="device_model">Device Model
                        <input type="text" name="device_model" id="device_model" class="form-control" value="<?= $row['device_model']; ?>"/></label>
                        <label for="phone_alias">Phone Alias
                        <input type="text" name="phone_alias" id="phone_alias" class="form-control" value="<?= $row['phone_alias']; ?>"/></label>
                        <label for="chauffeur_number">Chauffeur #
                        <input type="text" name="chauffeur_number" id="chauffeur_number" class="form-control" value="<?= $row['chauffeur_number']; ?>"/></label>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="update">Check Out</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<div class="row">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Phone #</th>
                        <th>Device ID</th>
                        <th>Device Manufacturer</th>
                        <th>Device Model</th>
                        <th>Phone Alias</th>
                        <th>Chauffeur #</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <?php $sql = 'SELECT * FROM phone_inventory ORDER BY id ASC';
                            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'. $row['id'] .'" href="#myModal" >View</a></td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['phone_number'] .'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['device_id'] .'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['device_manufacturer'] .'</td>';                                                                                              
                                echo '<td>'. $row['device_model'] .'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['phone_alias'] .'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['chauffeur_number'] .'</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                        }
                            Database::disconnect();
                        ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <?php include('../includes/js_scripts.php'); ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.table').dataTable( {
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "iDisplayLength": 10
            } );
        } );
    $(".device").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $("#myModal").find("#id").val(id);
        $("#myModal").dialog("open");
    })


    $(".alert").delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(4000);

     $(function() {
//twitter bootstrap script
        $("button#update").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: $('form.test').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                             $("#modal-results").html(msg)
                            $("#myModal").modal('hide');    
                         },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                    }
                      });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Post your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I think I understand what you need. You've got a results page, and you want to have a link in each of the results, that will bring up the detail page of the result in a modal.

So let's take it one step at a time. Get your link to the detail page working. Once that works correctly, we hijack it with AJAX, and display the page in the modal.

Bootstrap does AJAX modals easily, look at the `remote` option:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

`<a href="detail.php?id=123" data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal" data-target="#modal">Link Text</a>`

Let me know how it goes, no shame in being new to something :D

Comment: Ok, so i added what you put but changed the 123 to my $row['id'] and it works in a way that no modal pops up but a faded out screen and just plan text from the "getPhone.php" page shows. (which i just echoed out stuff)

Comment: OK great. It sounds like you're on the right track, just missing some of the modal code. You're getting the modal backdrop, just not the modal body. Poke around a bit more, you're almost there :D

Comment: Question, After a submit the modal goes away but the page doesn't refresh to show something has been updated or added. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you maybe want to force a refresh of the page after the submit? Or maybe you need to display the message via AJAX.

Comment: What I want to do is anytime the modal is submitted, to close the modal and then refresh the current page. Now, I changed my button type to submit but that did work just didn't post. then i thought maybe change to .click to .submit but that didn't do anything. also when i did that. the url changed to "?whatever=whatever" etc. but never posted.. idk.

Comment: It sounds like you want to listen to the AJAX request, and hook into it's callback. Once the form is submitted successfully, you want to close the modal and refresh the page.

Comment: Yeah. I know how to do it in php obviously but when it comes to javascript/jquery I am still new to it. That's why I am not sure on how to get the information and then pass it to php to show(echo) out into the form in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I think I understand what you need. You've got a results page, and you want to have a link in each of the results, that will bring up the detail form in edit in use a single model open and field in the row edit data.

> please follow this script to **Edit(Update)** data in a single model.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* if double click on table row then open model and fill all data in form */
    $('#table-id tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
        var table = $('#table-id').DataTable();
        var data = table.row(this).data();

        $("#phone_number").val(data.phone_number);
        $("#device_manufacturer").val(data.device_manufacturer);
        $("#device_model").val(data.device_model);
        $("#phone_alias").val(data.phone_alias);
        $("#chauffeur_number").val(data.chauffeur_number);
        $("#device_model").val(data.device_model);

        $("#modal-resultsl").modal('show');
    });

     /* if model close then all field is blank in open model in form */
     $('#con-close-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function() {
        /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
        $('#Form-id input[type="text"]').val('');
        /*Clear all input type="number" box*/
        $('#Form-id input[type="number"]').val('');
    });
</script>
```